# If i have a sine table, should i query the whole table into memory on wakeup?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, lookup, trigonometry

If i have a sine table, should i query the whole table into memory on wakeup?
Or should i query the table one every `Sin(...)` call? It seems a little more expensive to me to be hitting the database on every call of `Sin(...)`, would it be correct practice to just cache the whole table into C# memory on wakeup?

Comment: How many rows do you have in this table? I wouldn't expect much more than 1000.. In which case, definitely keep it in memory - in fact, just pregenerate it with `Math.Sin`, you don't need a database.

Comment: In fact, are you sure you need a table? Is calling `Math.Sin` on the fly measurably too slow? It's infinitely faster than hitting the database.

Comment: im new to sql so trying to practice with lookup tables

Comment: Alright, well for a smallish lookup table that doesn't change - yes, definitely load it into memory on start.

Comment: If you trying to learn SQL manipulations why would you even load that in memory - make whatever you need to be SQL query... Whole thing sound like bad idea as practical question - there is no way loading data from DB would be better than computing that table every time....

Comment: i guess what i meant is that i understand sql but using c# and sql together is what i am trying to practice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just using `Math.Sin` will be *much* faster than hitting the database, and not much slower than using an in-memory lookup table. This isn't really a good candidate for using a lookup table.

However, since you commented that you're just practising - yes, for a small table that doesn't change often (or ever), you should load it into memory on startup.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how many times you need to compute `sin` in your program's lifetime. If you need to do it once or twice an hour, querying DB or storing the table in memory makes no difference.

If you need to query `sin` often, storing the table in memory would make more sense. It goes without saying that lookups in the in-memory table need to be done in an efficient way: running a linear search on a million-row table in a tight loop could kill performance, even in comparison to a database alternative.